# Sonar is not able to find SVN command after installing SCM Activity plugin

Tags: svn, plugins, version-control, sonarqube

I've just installed SCM Activity plugin 1.5 in Sonar 3.2 following the [installation procedure](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin#SCMActivityPlugin-UsageInstallation). So Subversion is also available on the server where Sonar is installed as well. Moreover I've checked that svn is available on the command prompt.

However as soon as I start a jenkins job to run Sonar metrics, I've got the following warning in the output console:

```
[INFO] [11:17:24.504] Retrieve SCM info for /home/jenkins/jenkins-workspace/jobs/fhome-module-base-model_METRICS/workspace/src/main/java/com/mainsys/fhome/module/base/model/validation/ValidationResult.java
[INFO] [11:17:24.505] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/jenkins-workspace/jobs/fhome-module-base-model_METRICS/workspace/src/main/java/com/mainsys/fhome/module/base/model/validation && svn --username sonar --password '*****' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert blame --xml ValidationResult.java
[INFO] [11:17:24.506] Working directory: /home/jenkins/jenkins-workspace/jobs/fhome-module-base-model_METRICS/workspace/src/main/java/com/mainsys/fhome/module/base/model/validation
[WARN] [11:17:24.523] Fail to retrieve SCM info of: /home/jenkins/jenkins-workspace/jobs/fhome-module-base-model_METRICS/workspace/src/main/java/com/mainsys/fhome/module/base/model/validation/ValidationResult.java. Reason: The svn command failed.
/bin/sh: svn: not found
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn executable is probably available in your path but not in the path of the user that executes Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice for your quick reply. I though also that this might be the cause of the issue. However when I connect to the server using the user 'sonar' to start Sonar, I'm also able to use svn command line. That's why I don't understand Sonar is not able to see the svn command as well.

Comment: How can I verify svn executable is in the path of Sonar ?

Comment: I've just read again your answer carefully... Do you mean that SVN should be installed on the Jenkins server and not the Sonar server ?

Comment: I've just installed SVN on Jenkins server instead of Sonar server and now, everything is working as expected. Could you then update the installation procedure to specify that SVN should not be installed on the Sonar server. The following line is too confusing in the documentation: "All SCM providers currently require the native executable to be installed on the box."

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for your super fast support on this issue ;-)